# spring data mongodb @Query to find last item in an array

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have to get the last item of an array (embedded document) in Mongo database using spring data repository query for the below code, 
i.e., for the below document, I have to find the last product of the customer using @Query, could you please help ?

**Spring data Repository Class:**

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {
    @Query(??????)
    Product findLastProduct(String name);
}
```

**document inside Mongo database:**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5799d381e8d3966825444dc3"), 
"_class" : "com.xyz.models.Customer", 
"name" : "Sara", 
"createdBy" : "John", 
"createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-07-28T09:42:25.055Z"), 
"products" : [ { "name" : "product1", "deliveryPriority" : "LOW" }, { "name" : "product2", "deliveryPriority" : "MEDIUM" } ] 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried building any query to achieve this?

Comment: I could not get a clue on how to do that ? I tried to google, but no luck.

Comment: @developer did you find a solution for this?